Fill out the application form(,) and we will contact you
Which is correct:

Fill out the application form and we will contact you.
Fill out the application form, and we will contact you.


Either is fine, it’s a stylistic choice. One practice is that when each conjunct is a valid sentence (as here), one uses a comma if their subjects are distinct (as here: you and we).

"a stylistic choice"? What's the difference between these two "styles" then?

I’m not saying that there exist style A and style B, only that it is a matter of the author’s preference.

Or, shall we say, you are too shy to state that 'One practice' is actually 'prescriptive grammar'?

I don’t believe myself to be shy about flagging when my remarks are prescriptive (and I don’t believe that they often are meant as prescriptions). But anyway, here you asked which is correct. The notion of correctness is something of a fish out of water in descriptive accounts of language.

“One practice is…” is a description of how language is used. It amounts to “Some writers…”

@PaulTanenbaum So, which option is predominantly chosen by the more educated writers who are native speakers of English?

We often use a comma where a person saying the sentence aloud would pause for breath. As this is a short sentence, there is no particular reason to include the comma, but it wouldn't be 'wrong' to do so.

@KateBunting Thanks! I forgot that it would depend on the length of the sentence. I would think there are other punctuation options, for instance, 'Fill out the application form - and we will contact you.', though not 'Fill out the application form. And we will contact you.'

To summarise some comments - both are correct enough, and the difference is so minute that no one would ever look twice.
That said, from a very formal (and probably outdated) perspective, the second one would be more correct. You should include a comma when the two clauses ("fill out the application form", "we will contact you") being joined by a conjunction ("and") are complete and self-standing.
But no one living would call you up on it or likely even notice.
